# reading log file having dictionaries into python as dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a log file having lines in this format:

```
{"headers": {"ai5": "df9752bca47ff5efb3dd85291eaca875", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.5.1"}, "post": {"event": "ggstop", "ts": "1462759197931"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.690341", "game_id": "10655437"}}

{"headers": {"ai5": "df9752bca47ff5efb3dd85291eaca875", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.5.1"}, "post": {"event": "ggstart", "ts": "1462759198073"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.694609", "game_id": "10655437"}}

{"headers": {"ai5": "aca6d26817f1898723ff6c7abe3ee9dd", "debug": null, "random": null, "sdkv": "7.5.1"}, "post": {"event": "ggstop", "ts": "1462759198255"}, "params": {}, "bottle": {"timestamp": "2016-05-09 02:00:00.697425", "game_id": "10655437"}}
```

I want to read it into python as dictionary.
from each line I want "ai5", "timestamp", "event" and "ts".

I tried this:

```
my_dict = {}

with open("sample.log", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        key, values = items[0], items[1:]
        my_dict[key] = values


print my_dict
```

But, I failed miserably. File is pretty large. Please help!

Comment: have you tried ast.literal_eval? you can read strings of dictionaries into python dict type.

Comment: What after you get those key value pairs? Write it to another file?

Comment: @AlexFung these are not valid Python literals - it is JSON.

Comment: @AlexFung `null` will throw error with ast.literal_eval. json.loads is the way to go.

Comment: @MYGz True guess you can replace null with "null" then convert to None after. json.loads is better.

Comment: @AlexFung You can. But don't know what else is hiding there in that large file. `true`, `false`, etc.

Comment: @vaibhav chawla Did you figure out the solution yet??